# PNG Image Quality in PIL

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, png, python-imaging-library

Have been trying to upload the following png file to google cloud storage through app engine:

[image]

Before the upload, I'm running this through PIL to take care of any image rotations or changes in background color etc

However, I'm getting really bad image quality when running PIL manipulations through the app even though running the same commands in python command line comes out fine

[image]

Anybody have ideas?

For the PIL commands, I'm just running the following:

```
imtemp = Image.open('/[path]/logo.png')
size = max(imtemp.size[0],imtemp.size[1]) 
im = Image.new('RGBA', (size,size), (255,255,255,0))
im.paste(imtemp, ((size-imtemp.size[0])/2,(size-imtemp.size[1])/2)) 
imtemp = im 
im = Image.new('RGB', (size,size), '#FFFFFF') 
im.paste(imtemp, (0,0), imtemp) 
im.show()
```

Have tried below, but still no luck

```
    imtemp = Image.open(StringIO(imagedata)).convert("RGBA")
    im = Image.new("RGB", imtemp.size, "#FFFFFF")
    im.paste(imtemp, None, imtemp)
    imageoutput = StringIO()
    im.save(imageoutput, format="PNG", quality=85, optimize=True, progressive=True)
    imageoutput = imageoutput.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to take a palettized image, possibly with transparent pixels, project it on a white background and make  a quality-resized version of it which is half as big.

You can use the `convert()` and `thumbnail()` function for this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the image and convert it to RGBA.
orig = Image.open("fresh.png").convert("RGBA")

# Paste it onto a white background.
im = Image.new("RGB", orig.size, "#ffffff")
im.paste(orig, None, orig)

# Now a quality downsize.
w, h = im.size
im.thumbnail((w / 2, h / 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.show()
```

Of course, you can leave the `thumbnail()` call out if you want the image at the original size.

Comment: tried your solution and it still seems to be giving the same result... any clues from the code edit above?

Comment: No sorry, you're introducing a `StringIO` object which you initialize with some `imagedata` (where does that come from?). The next step, creating a white background and pasting the transparent image over it seems OK to me, but then I see you saving it to a `StringIO` with all kinds of options. Have you tried a simple `im.save("output.png")`? It seems you confuse many subproblems into one, like opening a picture, converting it, saving it to somewhere. Is there a reason why you use all these `StringIO`s all of a sudden?

Comment: AppEngine file system is readonly, so writing to buffers to save elsewhere is typical.

Comment: Yes, have tried a basic save with no other args but the result is the same.. 

The imagedata is coming from a webapp2 get from a form file input. I know the issue is in this code set because I can directly upload the imagedata to cloud storage and the image quality is fine

So somewhere in the StringIO or PIL manipulation, the image is downgraded -- feels like it is during the conversion to RGB? I'm still not entirely sure how this works but is it possible to save the file using the original palette... ie a good test may be just opening then saving the image without any unintended processing

Comment: @Dennis And what if you first download the image to your local computer, and do the processing there? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Tried it on the local and it seems fine. Only issue is when it gets moved to server... I also tried removing the transparency with photoshop before upload and the image turns out fine even on server